# Firebase Auth google provider invalid_request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a weird error when trying to use the google auth provider, it throws `invalid_request`

```
const googleLogin = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
googleLogin.addScope('profile')
googleLogin.addScope('email')

const login = provider => cb => auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
```

Microsoft is not working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the `Support Email`, you can go to `Project Overview` -> `Permissions` -> `General`.

I'm not sure about Microsoft, probably you can share some code.